# How to parse JSON array using Jersey Rest Webservices and Java

Tags: java, json, web-services, jersey, arrays

I am getting Json array from iOS client and want to parse the Json in server side using Java and jersey and Gson. I am sending the JSON array in POST method from iOS. I want to consume the json but stuck on how do i save the json data in Java class. This is the structure of my Json array

```
{
    "friendList": [
      {"id": 1, "username": "user1", "name":"person1", "friendUsername":"fUser1", "friendName":"fName1"},
      {"id": 2, "username": "user2", "name":"person2", "friendUsername":"fUser2", "friendName":"fName2"},
      {"id": 3, "username": "user3", "name":"person3", "friendUsername":"fUser3", "friendName":"fName3"},...
    ]
}
```

Here is my web services Class

```
@Path("/FriendsList")
public class RestWebServicesAPI {


     @POST
     @Path("/friends")
     @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     public Friends saveFriedList(Friends friend, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {

        // Don't know how to parse json array????

     }


}
```

and Here is my Friends Class

```
import java.util.List; 

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement; 

@XmlRootElement 

Public Class Friends {

    private String id; 
    private String username; 
    private String name; 
    private String friendUsername; 
    private String friendName;  

    public Friends() { 
    } 

   //getter setter methods

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have to do simply like this:

```
@Path("/FriendsList")
public class RestWebServicesAPI{

@POST
@Path("/friends")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Friends saveFriendList(final String json){
    Gson gs = new Gson();
    Friends [] n = gs.fromJson(json, Friends [].class);

}
//ALTERNATIVE
@POST
    @Path("/friends")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Friends saveFriendList(final Friends[] friends){


    }
```

Comment: how to map each json value with variables in friends class?

Comment: If you want to parse a json in a rest service my edited answer may works

Comment: in the first case of my code get a json that it parses with GSON in an array of Friends (GSON do the parse automatically); in the second Rest automatically parse the Json received in an array of Friends

Comment: is my Friends class code correct or do I need to match it with the JSON?

Comment: the var name and the name of the param in the json must be the same, this is the only condition

Comment: ok, the class seems ok, but in your json string you've got an "error".
Your first friend item got an "friendUsername" that is not correct, it must be "friendUserID".

Comment: ok thanks it's actually friendUsername, I have edited it. Will try to run again and update

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the below source

```
@POST
@Path("/friends")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Friends saveFriendList(Friends friends){
 // saveFriend function should have business logic to store your data in db
 friends= saveFriend(friends);
}
```

Comment: thanks..i didn't understand the saveFriend(friends), you mean i need to create the saveFriend method in the Friends class which takes the friend object and saves data in database? could you help me with some code for Friends class.