# The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are: application/json; charset=UTF-8

Tags: ajax, web-services, rest, cordova, jax-rs

I am developing a phonegap application where I need to post JSON data from phonegap to rest web service.

ajax call:

```
var data = {"name" : "abc"};
     $.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                          // url: "http://192.168.3.243:8090/ws/welcome",
                          url: "http://192.168.3.243:8090/TestExample/rest/welcome",
                         // url: "http://192.168.3.125:8080/JustInReporter/rest/test",
                           data: JSON.stringify(data),
                           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                           dataType: "application/json",
                           success: function (response) {
                           console.log(" **** success ** "+response);
                           }
                           });
```

Rest service:

```
@Path("/welcome")
public class WelcomeImpl 
{

    @POST
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public WelcomeForm welcome(WelcomeForm welcomeFormObject) 
   {

       WelcomeForm form = new WelcomeForm();
       form.title = " Connected ... ";
       System.out.println("welcomeFormObject *** "+welcomeFormObject.title);
       return form;

   }
}

@XmlRootElement
public class WelcomeForm
{

   public String title;


   public WelcomeForm()
   {
       title = "";
   }

   public WelcomeForm(String inTitle){
       title = inTitle;
   }


}
```

when I run the application I am getting this error at server side:

SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class com.test.beancls.WelcomeForm, and Java type class com.test.beancls.WelcomeForm, and MIME media type application/json; charset=UTF-8 was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json; charset=UTF-8 ->

```
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
```

can you tell me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with a more specific bean. In your JSON, you are sending "name" attribute as a part of the main body. So you should have a matching data structure. This may also be accomplished via annotations but as a start this should suffice

```
public class WelcomeForm
{

   public String name;


   public WelcomeForm()
   {
       title = "";
   }

   public WelcomeForm(String inTitle){
       name = inTitle;
   }

   public String getName(){ return name;}

   public void setName(String name){ this.name = name;}

}
```

And rest service to accept your data can be:

```
@Path("/welcome")
public class WelcomeImpl 
{

   @POST
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public WelcomeForm welcome(WelcomeForm welcomeFormObject) 
   {

       WelcomeForm form = new WelcomeForm();
       form.title = " Connected ... ";
       System.out.println("welcomeFormObject *** "+welcomeFormObject.title);
       return form;

   }

   @POST
   @Path("list")
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public WelcomeForm welcome(WelcomeForm[] welcomeFormObjects) 
   {
       // the path has changed to /welcome/list just to avoid ambiguity
       // do whatever you do with the array of objects 
   }
}
```

Comment: my json data is like  [
   {
     "scandName": "hdjdido",
     "cmpnyName": "Regency Towers ",
"address": "2511 South ",
"phnNum1": "8516 ",
    "phnNum2": "0700 ",
     "emailId": "gm@gmail.com ",
     "designation": "G.M."
   },
   {
    "scandName": "mukesh",
    "cmpnyName": "Economy",
   "address": "3500 west",
     "phnNum1": "7541 ",
    "phnNum2": "7541 ",
     "emailId": "economy@gmail.com ",
    "designation": "Manager"
   }]  this

Comment: just for trial i put the array like {"name" : "abc"}

Comment: are you trying to send an array or just a single object?

Comment: I am using an array. now if i send the data {"sdc":"sdcd"},{"ddd":"dd"} it is posting to server. But when I send the data [{"sdc":"sdcd"},{"ddd":"dd"}] it is not posting .

Comment: In your rest service, you only accept a single object. But then you send an array of objects which was not acceptable by your REST service method. You should modify your method in order to accept the array. The "alternative" way here in this post may be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20991454/1538022 . I also updated the answer to reflect that